¿Cómo puedo recorrer una variable en una campo generado de manera dinámica con Django?
Hola lo que pasa es que estoy generando los siguientes campos de manera dinámica con el for y necesito pasarle la variable en el atributo value de los campos generados, necesito llamar variables cómo A_c1, A_c2, A_c3, A_c4 y pensaba hacerlo con la variable number_c la cual estoy pasando en un rango para generar inicialmente...
Todo esto corresponde a la migración de un proyecto por lo cual la idea en esta parte es hacer la menor cantidad de cambios posibles, ya que esto llevaría a una reestructuración mayor de otras funcionalidades del código, agradezco su ayuda.
  <form class="ui form attached fluid segment" onsubmit="return false;">
    <div class="pulses">
      {% for number_c in range %}
      <div class="three fields" data-pulse="{{ number_c }}">
        <div class="field">
          <label>Intensidad {{ number_c }}</label>
          <input class="simParam" data-param="A_c{{ number_c }}" type="text"
                 value="{{ data['A_c'|add:number_c|stringformat:'d'] }}" />
        </div>
        <div class="field">
          <label>Semana inicial {{ number_c }}</label>
          <input class="simParam" data-param="t0_c{{ number_c }}" type="text"
                 value="{{ data.t0_c1 }}" />
        </div>
        <div class="field">
          <label>Duración {{ number_c }}</label>
          <input class="simParam" data-param="dt_c{{ number_c }}" type="text"
                 value="{{ data.dt_c1 }}" />
        </div>
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <div class="three fields">
      <div class="six wide field">
        <div class="ui button fluid" onclick="resetParams(5)" data-position="bottom center"
          data-tooltip="Reestablece todos los parámetros a su configuración inicial">Reestablecer</div>
      </div>
      <div class="six wide field">
        <div class="ui teal button fluid" onclick="toggleParams()" data-position="bottom center"
          data-tooltip="Muestra todos los parámetros del modelo">Opciones avanzadas</div>
      </div>
      <div class="four wide field">
        <div id="btnSim" class="ui blue submit button fluid" onclick="makeSimulation()">Simular</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>

